# what is the best way to dispose resources in GetX flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

I'm building a project using GetX flutter. What is the best way to dispose app resources (such as Text Editing Controllers and Animation Controllers)? as I know I can override the super method `onClose()` to dispose these resources, but we have also another super method, `dispose()`, so which one of these two method should I use?

Answer (score 2):

According to rx_disposable.dart file:

```
/// Called before [onDelete] method. [onClose] might be used to
/// dispose resources used by the controller. Like closing events,
/// or streams before the controller is destroyed.
/// Or dispose objects that can potentially create some memory leaks,
/// like TextEditingControllers, AnimationControllers.
/// Might be useful as well to persist some data on disk.
@override
void onClose() {
  super.onClose();
}
```

So you should use onClose() method.